# Vectorizing creation of array of diagonal matrix,

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a 2d array called diagonals where each row represents the diagonal of a 2d matrix. What's the fastest/best way to create a 3d array diag_matricies where the last two dimensions each consist of a diagonal matrix created using the rows of diagonals?

In a loop this is what I want:

```
import numpy as np

diag_matricies = np.zeros([3,3,3])
diagonals = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

for i in range(3):
    diag_matricies[i] = np.diag(diagonals[i,:]) 

print(diag_matricies)
```

Answer (score 1):

One faster alternative is to use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
index = np.arange(3)
diag_matricies[:, index, index] = diagonals

[[[1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 2. 0.]
  [0. 0. 3.]]

 [[4. 0. 0.]
  [0. 5. 0.]
  [0. 0. 6.]]

 [[7. 0. 0.]
  [0. 8. 0.]
  [0. 0. 9.]]]
```

*Timing* with the size of each dimension being 1200:

```
from datetime import datetime
N = 1200
diag_matricies = np.zeros([N, N, N])
diagonals = np.arange(N * N).reshape((N, N))

start = datetime.now()
index = np.arange(N)
diag_matricies[:, index, index] = diagonals
print('advanced indexing: ', datetime.now() - start)

start = datetime.now()
for i in range(N):
    diag_matricies[i] = np.diag(diagonals[i])
print('for loop: ', datetime.now() - start)

# advanced indexing:  0:00:01.537120
# for loop:  0:00:07.281833
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.einsum`:

```
>>> out = np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> np.einsum('ijj->ij',out)[...] = diagonals
>>> out
array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3.]],

       [[4., 0., 0.],
        [0., 5., 0.],
        [0., 0., 6.]],

       [[7., 0., 0.],
        [0., 8., 0.],
        [0., 0., 9.]]])
```

What this does under the hood is more or less the following:

```
>>> out2 = np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> out2.reshape(3,9)[:,::4] = diagonals
>>> out2
array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3.]],

       [[4., 0., 0.],
        [0., 5., 0.],
        [0., 0., 6.]],

       [[7., 0., 0.],
        [0., 8., 0.],
        [0., 0., 9.]]])
```

only the `einsum` method also works for noncontiguous arrays.